# First React-Bootstrap Radio Button Click is not triggering "touched" in Formik Form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bogdan-rdf1q

I have a React-Bootstrap radio group inside a Formik form. If you click on `Option 2` you'll notice that I correctly get a validation error on that field right away, but I do not get **touched** on that field right away, which I should. Instead I have to click the `Option 2` radio button ***again*** to get it inside the Formik **touched** array. So the touch is not registering on my 1st click if I start from that radiobutton, although the error is (correctly). The touch is registering on subsequent clicks.

```
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control type="radio"
                        id="option1"
                        name="group"
                        value="Y"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <Form.Label htmlFor="option1">Option 1 </Form.Label>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control type="radio"
                        id="option2"
                        name="group"
                        value="N"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <Form.Label htmlFor="option2">Option 2 </Form.Label>
        </Form.Group>
```

Validation:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    group: Yup.string().nullable().required('Required')
                                  .matches(/^Y$/,'Option 1 must be selected')
  })}
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Radiobuttons **stay focused** after selection, so the first update of `.touched` will only happen when you click somewhere else to blur the control after your 1st click.

This can be fixed by doing

```
  onChange={e => {
    // Note: Since radio buttons remain focused after selection,
    // we need to manually blur them to immediately update .touched
    // (including the first click)                                                                  
    e.currentTarget.blur();
    handleChange(e);
  }}
```